# React Material UI Autocomplete avoid getOptionSelected

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, axios, material-ui

I'm using a Material UI Autocomplete component for my React application, and it was working fine, however, giving me the error of none of the options match the selected value. Didn't cause any troubles, but I thought the terminal warning was annoying - so I wanted to get rid of it.

The reason I get the error, is basically because I use async requests with intermediary results for looking up street names. So when a user types in e.g. Oxf it would start to put Oxford Street as one of the options. The user can then click that option, and get even more options, e.g. it would not prompt selections like "334-348 Oxford Street" etc.

So basically, if the user hasn't typed a lot yet, the initial options will just be Street names (which in itself is not a valid input but just an intermediary result), which should prompt further options.

My question is therefore, how can I get rid of the getOptionSelected at all and force it to not evaluate this? Because as soon as they select an option, they are either prompted new options (in case of selecting a street name - and the selected option thus never match the new options which causes the error) or they will submit the address directly (i.e. by clicking the address will redirect them to the results).

Right now I have made a temporary solution where I just forces it to put the first option of the new prompts to be the `selected` one which puts a dark-grey background on it. So essentially I want to get rid of the dark-grey background.

Looks like this: `getOptionSelected={(option, value) => (options.indexOf(option) === 0 ? true : false)}`

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  option: {
    '&[aria-selected="true"]': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
});
```

Find more information in the Material UI Autocomplete sample found here:

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#githubs-picker